# MDL -dialog with angular 4

Tags: angular2-mdl

Usign MDL_dialog from Angular2-mdl and it has stop working after upgrade to angular 4.

Get -Renderer.animate is no longer supported!

Tried to upgrade Angular2 -mdl but cannot install it wiht angular 4.
Any ideas?

Comment: which version of angular2-mdl are you using?

Comment: "^2.13.2", @michael

Comment: ok. please use @angular-mdl/core  - see https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl#installation

Comment: Thanks! Had tried that but hadn't unstall the old. Tried again and it worked. Big thanks!